# Beginner Firebase User FCM Set-Up Questions

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-analytics

FOR iOS

Notifications

Cannot see an option for in app pop up messsages - is it only push/re-engagement message types?

Can the notifcations be automated not just scheduled one by one? Can this be done programatically? I.e. Something left in basket so send automatic push

Can the notifications be triggered based on in app user behaviour not just audience or property and can they have a time lag e.g. 3 days after trigger? I.e. User clicked on X promotion and hasn't returned in 2 days

Active Users 1, 7, 30 day

Accuracy of data - how reliable is the Firebase Active user data - what is the definition of actives reported?

Viewing new vs returning? Is this possible? I cannot find a view of this in the dashboard?

User Properties

When you add the code for the setUserProperty() once is is registered how does Firebase start to gather than data on this user property value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot see an option for in app pop up messsages - is it only
>   push/re-engagement message types?

FCM is for Notifications and data messages. At this time, if you want messages to appear in the app, you would use a data payload and handle the appearance of a pop-up within your code. See [About FCM Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) for details on Notifications vs data messages.

> Can the notifcations be automated not just scheduled one by one? Can
>   this be done programatically? I.e. Something left in basket so send
>   automatic push

From the console, you can schedule notifications. If you want to automate based on events, I suggest you use a combination of [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/). Store the FCM tokens in the database for sending.

> Can the notifications be triggered based on in app user behaviour not
>   just audience or property and can they have a time lag e.g. 3 days
>   after trigger? I.e. User clicked on X promotion and hasn't returned in
>   2 days

As for a delay, that would be something you'd have to handle in your own server.

> Accuracy of data - how reliable is the Firebase Active user data -
>   what is the definition of actives reported?

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317517?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489), "An active user has engaged with an app in the device foreground, and has logged a `user_engagement` event."

> Viewing new vs returning? Is this possible? I cannot find a view of
>   this in the dashboard?

No, this is not possible. You can see the `first_open` event and extrapolate from that.

> When you add the code for the setUserProperty() once is is registered
>   how does Firebase start to gather than data on this user property
>   value?

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317519?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489), "User properties are effectively sticky event parameters that are automatically logged when you call `logEvent`."

Comment: Thanks very much - all understood. Much appreciated.